# Regular expression, read sentence until to comma

Tags: regex

My logs:

```
ASSFDSFD: Hdsg: <SOME TEXT>, tim: 1m
ASSFDSFF: Hgfdg: <SOME TEXT>, tim: 17m
ASSBBBBB: Hgfdgfd: <SOME TEXT>, tim: 19m
```

I want to divide it to 2 parts:

1. texts to comma `ASSBBBBB: Hgfdgfd: <SOME TEXT>`
2. rest of sentence `tim: 19m`

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(.*?),\s*?(.*)` regex pattern.

It is exactly "any characters, any number of repetitions" + "comma, one time" + "whitespace, zero or more times" + "any characters, any number of repetitions"

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI1qG2/4).

Note: if your text denoted as `SOME TEXT` can contain comma too - you need to use greedy version of first capturing group: `(.*),\s*?(.*)`. In this case it will consume as much text until comma as possible.